# using get/post request to log in account

Tags: javascript, authentication, http-post, http-get

I used a http-Get request to a url, and get back response body shown below, which contains the following java script. I want to use a POST request to somehow log in my account. It seems that the response contains all the functions needed to do so, but I'm really new to web programming, and I don't know how to do the log in here. Is there a way to see what are the actions options and parameters? I'm open to all kinds of suggestions. Thank you

```
 <title>Login Page</title>
 <link href="/ssologinint/css/login2css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="/ssologinint/css/login-mobile.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="/ssologinint/js/common.js"></script>
 <SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/javascript>var loginAttempt=1;</script>
 <!--IdcClientLoginForm=1-->
 <META name=viewport content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;         user-scalable=0;">
 </head>
 <body>
 <!-- Function to trigger form submission by pressing "Enter" -->
            <SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/javascript>
                    // used to detect whether login is through Mobile or tablet device
isMobile = 0;
autoFill = false;
function set_cookie ( name, value, exp_y, exp_m, exp_d, path, domain, secure ) {...}
function get_cookie ( cookie_name ) {...}
function del_cookie(name) {...}
function rememberUser() { ... }
function defaultFocus() { ... }

JavaScript is disabled in your browser currently.
Please Enable JavaScript in your Browser and Try again.

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to log into a third party website? If yes, they might have exposed an Authentication API.

Comment: I don't see any kind of login form at all here, or any code to submit values to a database.  Your page only seems to have a body asking the user to Enable JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Enable your JavaScript before anything.

Follow page explain how to enable JavaScript in browsers.
http://www.enable-javascript.com/

Comment: JavaScript has been enabled already, but I still get the same result